# Where is the private interface for my Objective-C class?

Tags: objective-c, interface, class-extensions

The tutorial book I'm reading told me to create a `GameViewController` file class, which I did, resulting in the following files showing on the left-hand side of Xcode:

GameViewController.h
GameViewController.m

Then just after this part in the book it talks about creating properties in the private interface.

The book is "Learning Objective-C by Developing iPhone Games", and I am now on *Chapter 4 - Alien Invaders*.

Could you please tell me where the private interface is located?

Answer (score 4):

It’s in the GameViewController.m file (since other classes will include your .h file). Something like

```
@interface GameViewController ()

@property (assign, nonatomic)   BOOL    showDebugInfo;

@end
```

Comment: FYI - this private interface is better know as the class extension.

Comment: Great! Thanks very much for your help guys 